# Is it possible to use API keys for WCF RESTful service hosted in Azure?

Tags: wcf, azure, api-key

The title is my question. I looked into this for a while and from what I am reading it seems like Azure doesn't support that and I was just hoping for some verification and clarification if that is the case? I implemented an API key in my web service which worked great on the local host but as soon as I deploy to Azure and use that endpoint it doesn't work. It seems as if Azure re-creates its own Web.Config file upon deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Azure apps uses your published web.config file unless you have explicitly overridden specific keys in app settings screen.

Comment: No I just added a <serviceAuthorization> section. I don't get why it would work fine running from local machine but when I run from the azure endpoint it does not accept it.